# Trying to get property 'layanan' of non-object in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-6

I want to foreach data that are referenced from other table, but i get this:

> “Trying to get property 'layanan' of non-object”.

So, I have 2 tables, Objeks and Layanans. Layanans can have many Objeks, I've already create it's foreign key and the query is working in the database but when I want to foreach Objeks and foreach `nama_layanan` that I got from Layanans, it gives me error...

Here's the detail

**Layanans Table**

```
$table->bigIncrements('layanans_id');
            $table->string('nama_layanan');
            $table->timestamps();
```

**Objeks Table**

```
$table->bigIncrements('objeks_id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('nama_layanan');
            $table->string('tipe_objeks');
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('nama_layanans')->references('layanans_id')->on('layanans')
            ->onUpdate('cascade')
            ->onDelete('cascade');
```

**Layanan.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Layanan extends Model
{
    protected $fillable=[
        'nama_layanan'
    ];

    protected $primaryKey = 'layanans_id';

    public function objek() {
        return $this->hasMany(Objek::class);
    }
}
```

**Objek.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Objek extends Model
{
    protected $fillable=[
        'nama_layanan', 'tipe_objeks'
    ];
    protected $primaryKey = 'objeks_id';

    public function layanan() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Layanan::class);
    }
}
```

This is my foreach
**object.blade.php**

```
@foreach ($data as $item)                   
                <tr>
                  <td>{!! $item->objeks_id !!}</td>
                  <td>{!! $item->objeks->layanan->nama_layanan !!}</td>
                  <td>{!! $item->tipe_objeks !!}</td>
                </tr>
                @endforeach
```

what is the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

```
<td>{!! $item->objeks->layanan->nama_layanan !!}</td>
```

You are pulling a *collection* of `objeks` from the `item` of data within the loop.  The collection will not have a property `layanan`, it has a bunch of `objeks` within.

If you want to get to the `layanan` property, you will either have to loop on the `objeks` in this loop, or call `first()` / `where()` to get to a specific *single* object at that level.

Additionally you haven't shown how you are getting the `$data`.  It is possible that you don't actually Have any `objeks` within that instance of `$item`, which would lead to the exact error you have.  If there is null `objeks` on this specific `item`, you can't pull the property from it.

Comment: this is how I get it

Comment: public function object(){
    $objek = \App\Objek::all();
    return view ('pages.alat.object.object')->with('data',$objek);
}

Comment: OK.  You have a collection of `objeks` but when you loop you are pulling `$item->objeks`.  There is no secondary object or collection.  Try: `<td>{!! $item->layanan->nama_layanan !!}</td>`

Comment: @agastyarimbawa -- was it successful with the fix above?

Comment: I did what you told before, now it says trying to get property 'nama_layanan' of non object...

Do I need to call 'use App\Layanan' and declare '$layanan = \App\Layanan::all();' in my controller and function?

Comment: So this correctly solved your problem.  The next problem is the exact same - apply the same logic and you'll be all set.

Comment: um... the thing is, I still get an error, where do I need to apply the same logic that you tell before?

Comment: and I want to get 'nama_layanan' from 'layanan' into my 'object' view